# AndroidManifest package name conflict with flavors in Android

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I am trying to make 2 flavors of my app.

Gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "be.myname.firstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23 }

productFlavors {
        raterate {
            applicationId = "be.myname.firstapp"
        }
        scarsforlife {
            applicationId = "be.myname.secondapp"
        }
    }
```

I have an AndroidManifest in the main folder, fistapp folder & secondapp folder.

Packagename in first folder: be.myname.fistapp, second folder: be.myname.secondapp.

In the main folder I first had: be.myname.firstapp, but that conflicted with be.myname.secondapp. Now I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="${packageId}">

</manifest>
```

And got this:

```
Attribute manifest@package at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-27 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <packageId> is provided.
AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-45 value=(be.myname.secondapp)
    has a different value=(be.myname.secondapp) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-27
    Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
        flavorName {
            applicationId = "be.myname.secondapp"
        }
```

I'm confused at this point. What is the correct way to do this? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to modify the package in `AndroidManifest.xml` for every flavors.

Quoting from [tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename):

> Therefore, we have decoupled the two usages of package name:
>
> - The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google
>     Play store, is the "application id".
> - The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations,
>     continues to be called the "package".
>
> You can specify the application id in your gradle file as follows:
>
> app/build.gradle:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>   compileSdkVersion 19
>   buildToolsVersion "19.1"
>
>   defaultConfig {
>       applicationId "com.example.my.app"
>       minSdkVersion 15
>       targetSdkVersion 19
>       versionCode 1
>       versionName "1.0"
>   }
>   ...
> ```
>
> As before, you need to specify the package used for your code in the
>   Manifest file, just as shown in the above AndroidManifest.xml sample.
>
> **Here comes the critical part**: When you've done the above, the two
>   packages are independent. You are completely free to refactor your
>   code - changing the internal package used for your activities and
>   services, updating your Manifest package, and refactoring your import
>   statements. This will have no bearing on the final id of your
>   application, which is now always going to be the applicationId
>   specified in the Gradle file.

Comment: So what are you supposed to use here: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="${packageId}">

Comment: seems that it should be the same value in all AndroidManifest.xml files